# How can I update Access with .ldb file present?

Tags: ms-access

With Access 2003, we have a msaccess database with some tables that resides on a server PC. Various users link to its tables from their forms and subforms.

If the **.ldb** file still exists, and I know there are no activities going on since it is an after hours thing, can I copy the **mdb** file to my PC, add couple of rows to its table and copy it back?

I am the only one updating it. I just can not get rid of the ldb file.

Comment: why you can not add some rows at server?

Comment: sometimes i have to do a batch and locally is faster. can i still?.

Comment: you can copy and if there are no writes to database file at server while process of copying, you will get working db in local file.

Comment: how much faster is a batch when done locally rather than remotely on the server?  what number of rows are being added/updated?  while the "copy to your PC" may succeed, it is the "copy it back" what will fail when the ldb indicates that some other user has it open.

Answer (score 0):

A LDB file is created when an Access database is opened/accessed by a user [you can read more here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/966848/what-is-an-ldb-file), LDB mechanism is critically needed in order to prevent multiple users modifying the same data simultaneously,

as long there's a LDB file you cant delete/move/replace the DB file, but you can still run Queries update/delete/alter only on records/tables that aren't locked with the LDB file, however you can always add records using insert into since rows that don't exist cant be locked (by other users).

(I have witnessed computers that were hit with crypto viruses and the access file was saved due to the LDB, but don't rely on it you should always have a backup)